# How to update data from recyclerview adapter in kotlin flow using MVVM architecture?

Tags: android-recyclerview, kotlin-coroutines, android-architecture-components, android-mvvm, android-paging

So, I am making something similar to instagram feed using MVVM architecture, coroutines, Jetpack.

I am displaying list of post in recyclerview using paging-3 library. Each post contains the images, likes count, share counts, comments count. Currently, my app is not using caching. So app is only rely on single data source from network.

I am having the problem in implementing the like/unlike functionality using MVVM. When user like or dislike some particular post, i am making network request to backend api with post_id. The api will return the latest likes count from server. And I want to update this like count in that particular post displaying in recyclerview.

But, I don't how to achieve this functionality using MVVM pattern and update that post data in Flow<PagingData>. I can not use viewModel inside RecyclerView.Adapter class for making network request.

So, how to achieve this functionality using MVVM and paging-3.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [Android : Leveraging RecyclerView Effectively with ViewModel](https://blog.hotstar.com/android-leveraging-recyclerview-effectively-with-viewmodel-d21867c81ab4) blog by Hotstar. Their approach is ***One ViewModel per RecyclerView item*** to overcome similar problems.

Comment: `Note: This RecyclerView cell ViewModel does not extend the android’s ViewModel class as the Fragment ViewModel does.` this is important because technically that would just cause bugs